# Spring XD Batch Job remote partitioning

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd, partition

I'm new to Spring XD so excuse my ignorance.

I have a spring batch job that runs fine as standalone.  I need to port it to spring XD, but with remote partitioning.
I have 3 XD containers (and 1 admin).  I have a redis server and a ZK.  All 3 containers run on different virtual machines.  I'm able to deploy my custom module to all containers and also create a job.

The problem is when I try to launch the job.

I'm getting this exception:

2016-06-24T17:12:31-0400 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR inbound.job:XD_SF_Fetch_Job.0-redis:queue-inbound-channel-adapter1 redis.RedisMessageBus$1 - Failed to deliver message; retries exhausted; message sent to queue 'ERRORS:job:XD_SF_Fetch_Job.0' org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.step.NoSuchStepException: No StepExecution could be located for this request: StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=2, stepExecutionId=31, stepName=step1]

### Below is my spring-module.xml (I've removed declarations that are easily assumed)

```
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring-xd/batch/singlestep-partition-support.xml"/>


    <!-- connect to database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property .... />
    </bean>
    <bean id="myBean" scope="step" class="org.me.MyBean" > </bean>
    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
            <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="partitioner" scope="step" class="com.me.Partitioner" >
            <property name="id" value="#{jobParameters['id']}" />
    </bean>

    <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet ref="myBean"/>
```

Below is my command list at the xd-shell prompt:

```
module upload --type job --force --name XD_MyModule --file module.jar
job create  --name XD_MyJob --definition "XD_MyModule --makeUnique=true"              
job deploy XD_MyJob --properties "module.XD_MyModule.count=3"
job launch XD_MyJob --params {"src":"/tmp/src1"}
```

I've setup such that custom modules are upload to a mounted location available to all 3 containers.

My assumption was that when I launch the job, one container will pick up the launch request and using the partitioner split the work into partitions.  I can actually see the logs from the partitioner which tells me it gets that far.  But looks like the partitionHandler is not able to distribute/communicate the step execution requests to the other containers.  I installed the redis and zk that came with the spring xd download.

Job Repo:
All the usual tables:

| BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION          |
| BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  |
| BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS   |
| BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ      |
| BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE           |
| BATCH_JOB_SEQ                |
| BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION         |
| BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT |
| BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ     |
| XD_JOB_REGISTRY              |
| XD_JOB_REGISTRY_STEP_NAMES   |

this is the one I find very weird (only 1 record)
mysql> select * from XD_JOB_REGISTRY_STEP_NAMES;
+-----------------+--------------+
| JOB_NAME        | STEP_NAME    |
+-----------------+--------------+
| XD_MyJob | step1-master |
+-----------------+--------------+

step1-master is defined in the imported singlestep-partition-support.xml

| STEP_EXECUTION_ID | VERSION | STEP_NAME                                        | JOB_EXECUTION_ID | START_TIME          | END_TIME | STATUS   | COMMIT_COUNT | READ_COUNT | FILTER_COUNT | WRITE_COUNT | READ_SKIP_COUNT | WRITE_SKIP_COUNT | PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT | ROLLBACK_COUNT | EXIT_CODE | EXIT_MESSAGE | LAST_UPDATED        |

|                 1 |       1 | step1-master                                     |                1 | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 | NULL     | STARTED  |            0 |          0 |            0 |           0 |               0 |                0 |                    0 |              0 | EXECUTING |              | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 |
|                 2 |       0 | step1-master:patition-Tm-AccountContactRole |                1 | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 | NULL     | STARTING |            0 |          0 |            0 |           0 |               0 |                0 |                    0 |              0 | EXECUTING |              | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 |
|                 3 |       0 | step1-master:patition-Tm-Account            |                1 | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 | NULL     | STARTING |            0 |          0 |            0 |           0 |               0 |                0 |                  0 |              0 | EXECUTING |              | 2016-07-03 10:10:25 |

All pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does your job repository look like?

Comment: I've updated with the list of tables in the repo.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in what is in the batch_step_execution table

Comment: I've updated with the table contents...3 rows.   Notice how the step name is 'step1-master:patition-Tm-Account'.

Comment: Are all your containers pointing to the same job repository?  It looks like they aren't.

Comment: [just got the SO alert a few minutes ago even though your comment was yesterday :( ]  Yes, all are using the same repo.  The repo is a mysql db.